# Laravel grouped routes throw HTTP 500 error

Tags: php, laravel, azure, routes, http-status-code-500

I've been working on a simple Laravel 8 application which I deployed to Azure web services. Somehow I can't seem to access my group routes, because the server responds with an HTTP 500 error.

The homepage and my /admin route are loading without any problems as well as my login and logout routes. The problem only occurs with my admin/users* and admin/organisations* routes.

I don't experience any problems when the app is running locally. It only happens once it's deployed to the webhost.

This is my route file:

```
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\LoginController;
use App\Http\Controllers\LogoutController;
use App\Http\Controllers\OrganisationController;
use App\Http\Controllers\UserController;
use App\Models\Organisation;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('home');
});

Route::get('/login',[LoginController::class, 'index'])->name('login')->middleware('guest');
Route::post('/login', [LoginController::class, 'store']);

Route::post('/logout', [LogoutController::class, 'store']);

Route::prefix('admin')->middleware(['auth', 'elevated'])->group(function() {
    Route::get('/', function() {return view('admin.boilerplate');});

        Route::prefix('users')->group(function() {
            Route::get('/', [UserController::class, 'showAll'])->name('users');

            Route::get('/new', [UserController::class, 'showNewUserform'])->name('createPage');
            Route::post('/', [UserController::class, 'createUser'])->name('createUser');

            Route::get('/{id}', [UserController::class, 'showById'])->name('userInfo');
            Route::delete('/{id}', [UserController::class, 'deleteById']);

            Route::get('/{id}/edit', [UserController::class, 'showEditUserform'])->name('editPage');
            Route::put('/{id}', [UserController::class, 'updateById'])->name('editUser');
        });

        Route::prefix('organisations')->group(function() {
            Route::get('/', [OrganisationController::class, 'showAll'])->name('organisations');

            Route::get('/new', [OrganisationController::class, 'showNewOrganisationform'])->name('createOrganisationPage');
            Route::post('/', [OrganisationController::class, 'createOrganisation'])->name('createOrganisation');

            Route::get('/{id}', [OrganisationController::class, 'showById'])->name('organisationInfo');

            Route::delete('/{id}', [OrganisationController::class, 'deleteById']);

            Route::get('/{id}/edit', [OrganisationController::class, 'showEditOrganisationform'])->name('editOrganisationPage');
            Route::put('/{id}', [OrganisationController::class, 'updateById'])->name('editOrganisation');
        });

});
```

My login controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Carbon;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        return view('login');
    }

    public function store(Request $request){

        $this->validate($request, [
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required'
        ]);

        if(!auth()->attempt($request->only('email', 'password'), $request->remember)){
            return back()->with('status', 'Invalid login credentials');
        };

        return redirect('/');
    }
}
```

My .htaccess file inside the Public folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

And my .htaccess file within the root of my project:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [NC,L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

That last file was needed in order to tell Azure to make my Public folder the rootdirectory instead of the default wwwroot folder that it would be looking for.

This is my User controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Organisation;
use App\Models\Role;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function showAll() {
        $users = User::with('role', 'organisation')->get();

        return view('admin.users.useroverview', compact('users'));
    }

    public function showById($id) {
        $user = User::find($id);
        $role = $user->role;

        return view('admin.users.userinfo', compact('user', 'role'));
    }

    public function showNewUserform() {
        if(auth()->user()->isAdmin()) {
            $roles = Role::all();
        }
        else
            $roles = Role::all()->where('rolename', '!=', 'admin');

        $organisations = Organisation::all();

        return view('admin.users.createuser', compact('roles', 'organisations'));
    }

    public function createUser(Request $request) {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'newUsername' => 'required|max:255',
            'newEmail' => 'required|email',
            'newRole' => 'required|not_in:0',
            'newOrganisation' => 'required|not_in:0',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed'
        ]);

        User::create([
            'username' => $request->newUsername,
            'email' => $request->newEmail,
            'role_id' => $request->newRole,
            'organisation_id' => $request->newOrganisation,
            'password' => Hash::make($request->password)
        ]);

        return redirect()->route('users');
    }

    /**
     * @throws \Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException
     */
    public function showEditUserform($id) {
        $this->authorize('edit', User::class);

        $user = User::find($id);
        $userRole = $user->role;
        $userOrganisation = $user->organisation;

        if(auth()->user()->isAdmin()) {
            $roles = Role::all()->where('rolename', '!=', $userRole->rolename);
        }
        else
            $roles = Role::all()->where('rolename', '!=', 'admin')
                ->where('rolename', '!=', $userRole->rolename);


        $organisations = Organisation::all()->where('id', '!=', $userOrganisation->id);

        return view('admin.users.edituser', compact('user', 'userRole', 'roles', 'organisations', 'userOrganisation'));
    }

    /**
     * @throws \Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException
     * @throws \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException
     */
    public function updateById(Request $request, $id) {
        $this->authorize('edit', User::class);

        $this->validate($request, [
            'updatedUsername' => 'required|max:255',
            'updatedEmail' => 'required|email',
            'updatedRole' => 'required|not_in:0',
            'updatedOrganisation' => 'required|not_in:0'
        ]);

        $currentUser = User::find($id);
        $currentUser->username = $request->updatedUsername;
        $currentUser->email = $request->updatedEmail;
        $currentUser->role_id = $request->updatedRole;
        $currentUser->organisation_id = $request->updatedOrganisation;
        $currentUser->save();

        return redirect()->route('userInfo', ['id'=>$id]);
    }

    /**
     * @throws \Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException
     */
    public function deleteById($id) {
        $this->authorize('delete', User::class);

        User::find($id)->delete();

        return redirect()->route('users');
    }

}
```

And my organisation controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Organisation;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

class OrganisationController extends Controller
{
    public function showAll() {
        $organisations = Organisation::with('users')->get();

        return view('admin.organisations.organisationoverview', compact('organisations'));
    }

    public function showById($id) {
        $organisation = Organisation::find($id);

        return view('admin.organisations.organisationinfo', compact('organisation'));
    }

    public function showNewOrganisationform() {
        return view('admin.organisations.createorganisation');
    }

    public function createOrganisation(Request $request) {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'newOrganisationName' => 'required|max:255',
            'newOrganisationEmail' => 'required|email',
            'description' => 'required|max:255'
        ]);

        Organisation::create([
            'name' => $request->newOrganisationName,
            'contact_email' => $request->newOrganisationEmail,
            'description' => $request->description
        ]);

        return redirect()->route('organisations');
    }

    public function showEditOrganisationform($id) {
        $this->authorize('edit', Organisation::class);
        $organisation = Organisation::find($id);

        return view('admin.organisations.editorganisation', compact('organisation'));
    }

    public function updateById(Request $request, $id) {
        $this->authorize('edit', Organisation::class);
        $this->validate($request, [
            'updatedOrganisationName' => 'required|max:255',
            'updatedOrganisationEmail' => 'required|email',
            'updatedDescription' => 'required|max:255'
        ]);

        $currentOrganisation = Organisation::find($id);
        $currentOrganisation->name = $request->updatedOrganisationName;
        $currentOrganisation->contact_email = $request->updatedOrganisationEmail;
        $currentOrganisation->description = $request->updatedDescription;
        $currentOrganisation->save();

        return redirect()->route('organisationInfo', ['id'=>$id]);
    }

    /**
     * @throws \Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException
     */
    public function deleteById($id) {
        $this->authorize('delete', Organisation::class);
        Organisation::find($id)->delete();

        return redirect()->route('organisations');
    }
}
```

This is my Login controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Carbon;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        return view('login');
    }

    public function store(Request $request){

        $this->validate($request, [
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required'
        ]);

        if(!auth()->attempt($request->only('email', 'password'), $request->remember)){
            return back()->with('status', 'Invalid login credentials');
        };

        return redirect('/');
    }
}
```

These are the Env variables that I configured in my Azure portal. Everything seems fine.

[image]

Furthermore I performed a refresh on all my caches within the Azure SSH using

> php artisan optimize

But that did not do the trick unfortanetely.

Does someone know what the problem could be? I'm using PHP 7.4 btw.

Comment: A 500 error message is generic error that can mean a number of things. Check the web servers error log to see what the actual error is.

Comment: Hi @M.Eriksson, when I check my deployment builder in Azure, it says this when I try to deploy a newer version of the app: Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  could not find driver (SQL: select * from `organisations`)
Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1

Comment: Make sure that all needed PHP extensions has been installed and enabled (specifically the extension for the database you're using). I have no idea how to do that in Azure though (never used it)

Comment: If it says `could not find driver`, then PHP doesn't have the extensions built in to access the database. If you're not using any queries on your regular routes, then they wouldn't be affected

Comment: @M.Eriksson When I run php -m in my Azure SSH, it does mention all the database modules that I require to perform the actions like: PDO and pdo_mysql. So the modules are there, but apparantly they aren't present.

Comment: @aynber But when I login, it's looking for me as a user in the database. That also requires some query'ing right? Somehow the web app manages to succesfully log me in and thus use a SQL statement.

Comment: Usually, there are different configs for CLI (when using SSH and php -m) and for the web server. The extensions can be installed and enabled for CLI but not for the web server. But if you say that you have other SQL queries that does work, then I'm at a loss.

Comment: @M.Eriksson If that's the case, then I need to find out how to configure this for the web server. I can't seem to find anything on the web nor in the Azure docs. Yeah indeed, the login action also requires database usage, so that kinda contradicts the assumption that it's a general database problem. But thanks though, I apppreciate you helping me.

Comment: @M.Eriksson, I've added my logincontroller in the OP for you the check in case you want some extra context.